# How do I look specifically at the ends of a string in python?

Tags: python, string, loops

I am trying to create a function that examines the ends of a string in python and returns an integer if it matches the conditions that I have defined, however i am having an issue with the numbers overlapping is there a way for me to get around this simply with just built in string functions and not using any import? so for example the string 'AAZZ' should return to me two but is returning four instead. The conditions are A matches with Z and it Y matches with C. the function will look for pairs to match until it runs into a pair that does not match where it will stop and return the value it has for count.
Here is what i have so far:

```
def matching(str):
    i = 0
    j = -1
    count = 0

    while i < len(str): 
        if str[i] == 'A' and str[j] == 'Z':
            i += 1
            j -= 1
            count += 1
        elif str[i] == 'Z' and str[j] == 'A':
            i += 1
            j -= 1
            count += 1    
        elif str[i] == 'Y' and str[j] == 'C':
            i += 1
            j -= 1
            count += 1  
        elif str[i] == 'C' and str[j] == 'Y':
            i += 1
            j -= 1
            count += 1          
        else:
            count = 0
    return count
```

Comment: You haven't said what the rules you're trying to implement are. Why does AAZZ return two?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure if you hit the `else` condition, you will *loop forever*

Comment: i managed to fix else to return count that should be fine thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition to `i < len(str) + j`, otherwise you'll be counting everything twice (once from each end).

Comment: Thank you for that catch, function seems to be fine now

Comment: In the future, it helps to fill out the edit comment accurately: Changing the OP's code is not "fixing indentation" and should be explained if you want your edit approved. I only noticed my mistake (and that your edit was correct) because I was going to comment about it being incorrect after the review. That being said, sorry.

Comment: @TemporalWolf are you referring to the fact I reverted his code to the original (without the `+j`)?

Comment: Yes: the review queue does not show context that that was reverting a previous edit. Without that information, it looks like you're *fixing* their code, which is harmful for future readers. A descriptive comment would likely prevent future misinterpretation.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Ok, I assumed it showed context the same way it does if I'm viewing the edit history. Will keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17884700) is all a reviewer sees, which, based on that information, it appears destructive, when it really isn't. Also, see [the comment I left](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47191492/revisions) which makes it clear *why* the edit was made :)